# 2D Int Array withing a Struct - C

Tags: c, arrays, gcc, struct

I declare the struct before main:

```
struct roomData
{
  float widthFeet, widthInch;
  float lengthFeet, lengthInch;
  char roomName[100];
  int roomNumberOfType;
  char roomType[6]; //char of room type
  int roomStock[101][6]; //for storing each room stock types
  int roomHasStock; //if the room has a stock avaliable
  int roomStockCount; //how many stocks the room has
  float area;  // sq ft
  float rentalRate;
  float profitsPerRoom;
  float netProfit;
  float grossProfit;
};
```

inside main, i declare the struct with this:

```
int main(void)
{
struct roomData rooms[MAXROOMS+1] = {0}; //struct for rooms(+1 for temp swapping in sorts)
}
```

later I pass the struct and a few other variables to a function with this code in main:

```
        fillRoomData(n, x, array, rooms, 1);
```

and the fillRoomData function is this:

```
    void fillRoomData(int n, int x, struct fileInput array[300], struct roomData rooms[MAXROOMS], int check)//NEED TO ERROR CHECK
{
    if(check == 1) //for stock values in room
    {
        char * word4; //for strTok
        word4 = strtok(array[n].input," "); //stockType
        rooms[x].roomStock[a][0] = atoi(word4); //sores stock number
        word4 = strtok(NULL, " "); //stockCount
        rooms[x].roomStock[a][1] = atoi(word4); //sores stock inventory
....

}
```

This is the error im getting from GCC after rdb

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000338f23473a in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x000000338f23473a in ____strtoll_l_internal () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x000000338f231bf2 in atoi () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x0000000000406ed9 in fillRoomData (n=29, x=0, array=0x7ffffffefcc0, 
    rooms=0x7ffffffd2fe0, check=1) at amp6572Lab4.c:1420
#3  0x0000000000400fde in main () at amp6572Lab4.c:279
(gdb) frame 2
#2  0x0000000000406ed9 in fillRoomData (n=29, x=0, array=0x7ffffffefcc0, 
    rooms=0x7ffffffd2fe0, check=1) at amp6572Lab4.c:1420
    1420                rooms[x].roomStock[a][b] = atoi(word4); //stores
```

Thanks So MUCH for all help!

Comment: You aren't showing enough code for this to be useful.  Show us how this struct is initialized and used; where in code the seg fault happens.

Comment: @tillerstarr thanks for your quick responce

, i have posted a answer to my own question with more code.

Comment: does word4 actually have a value in it?

Comment: @tillerstarr yes, word4 has some numbers like 213121, but they are in string format when inputted thus the atoi to convert them to int for the array

Comment: I meant when debugging and you get to that line in your code...word4 has the expected value filled via the strtok of array[n].input

Comment: I think you need to have a different data structure. You should never need 600 `int`s inside a single structure, that's a bit over 2 KB per structure! Consider using bit masks instead.

Comment: yep, i coded the program in codeblocks and everything works fine there. but when i put it into gcc it gives me the segmentation fault.
i tried to debug the code manually by placing print statements through the program, but i cant find the location

Comment: Print out `array[n].input` and `word4` to make sure their values are what you expect.

Comment: @DCoder the values are correct. the code works perfectly fine in Codeblocks with all of the correct values outputting, but when i get to GCC for my submission it gives me the error, would it be a good idea to post my full code on a txt file here?

Comment: what are `a` and `b`? You aren't showing the complete function.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your main to:

```
struct roomData rooms[MAXROOMS+1];
```

Comment: thats how it was initially, then i saw the error and changed it, still no good :/

Comment: what is MAXROOMS defined as?

Comment: its defined as 25 based on the assignment, would it be helpful if i pasted the full code here? with a link to a txt file or something?